# Add script tag to markdown file

Tags: javascript, markdown, mkdocs

I am developing document in MKdocs and need to load some script files to my markdown file. How can I add js functions and script tags in markdown?

Comment: Would this help? https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/styling-your-docs/#using-the-docs_dir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options: You could include raw HTML `<script>` tags in your Markdown, or you could use MkDocs' `extra_javascript` setting to point to your own JavaScript file.

### Use raw HTML

As the Markdown documentation [explains](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to
>   indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the
>   tags.
>
> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g.
>   `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. — must be separated from
>   surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the
>   block should not be indented with tabs or spaces.

Of course, any such scripts would be unique to the one page they are included on.

### Use `extra_javascript`

If you would like a script to be available on all of your pages, MkDocs provides the [extra_javascript](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#extra_javascript) configuration setting, which will cause a `script` which points to the specified file to be included on every page. Just make sure the file is available in your `docs_dir`.

For example, if you create a file `myscript.js`, then add the following to your `mkdocs.yml` config file:

```
extra_javascript:
    myscript.js
```